# Attenuating a 10V Sin wave [Circuit design]

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, impedance-matching

About a year ago I designed a circuit that takes a 10V analogue signal and converts it to a 5V level and gets read by an ADC etc.

Here's the original circuit:
*The AD620 has external pins for a single gain resistor, it has a gain of 1 in the circuit*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkujmv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've decided to revisit some of my old designs and was finding ways to improve upon what I previously built.

- With input limits of 0V and 10V my clamping diodes aren't needed at all, as the maximum limits I get after the voltage divider are 0V and 5V anyway.
- I buffer the singal, divide it down and then buffer it again which I think could be better implemented
- There is no impedance matching on the input of the AD620

I've redesigned the circuit and removed some components and added another resistor on the input and have come up with the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9cB5.png)</sup>

My signal source can supply 150mA so shouldn't have a problem driving the low impedance resistor.

**Question** - I guess my actual question is this, are these two circuits comparable? Or are there any better solutions?
Any other feedback or issues you see with either of my designs feel free to point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've actually made between your signal line & your AD8676 in the second diagram is a "pi attenuator."

While a pi attenuator could actually be used quite well in this instance, I think yours has the wrong resistor values.

Here's a link to a calculator made specifically for making impedance-matched pi attenuator circuits like that: [Pi Attenuator Calculator](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-pi-attn.aspx)

using that calculator, if your op-amp had an input impedance of 50ohms, the following would work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsFKQh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Since, however, the input of the OA is closer to 1Mohm than 50ohm, you'll probably want to do a little checking on **"Impedance Matching Pi Networks"** if you need to avoid reflections on the incoming signal cable.

---

EDIT

---

Or, if we stop over-complicating things on ourselves, using the fact that the op-amp's input can be considered infinite-impedance, compared to the 50-ohm required load, you could use this even simpler circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHnzAu.png)</sup>

Comment: +1 for the "Pi attentuator" I wasn't aware of this. My idea was to use the 50 ohms to match the impedance of the source and then just use a standard voltage divider after it.

Comment: Yes, I caught the idea...and actually tried to do exactly that myself once. In practice, though, you'll find that most of the current shunts through the 50ohm resistor, and you'll likely not get a very accurate reading from the 1K voltage divider. However, after another thought, I'll add an edit to my answer with a simpler-yet solution that *should* work perfectly, and with even fewer components.

Comment: @Doodle Please see answer edit. That solution gives both impedance-match & voltage-divider with the same 2 resistors (and I *really* should have thought of it sooner...lol)

Comment: In the edit, is the opamp input impedance 25 ohms or does it use the sum of both resistors?

Comment: To your signal source, the resistors are in series, with the Op-Amp providing a ~10Gohm (negligible) resistance in parallel to the 2nd one (so the signal source sees a 49.99999ohm load). To the Op-Amp, both the signal connection and the ground connection are 25ohms away from its input pin, so it's high-impedance input will see very nearly perfectly half the signal voltage. CAVEAT: if your input signal is a true, *unbalanced* signal, its level will fall below signal ground...you may still want to design for this somehow (coupling capacitor to voltage divider is the generally used method).

Comment: Guess I should explain that the caveat was based on the assumption that your input signal is ground-centered, such as most RF or Audio signals that I'd expect to see coming in through a BNC connection. If the incoming signal never falls below ground, please disregard that part.

Comment: Yeah that might be my mistake for saying it's a sine wave. It's probably more correct to say it's "10V p-p sinusoidal signal with 5V DC offset"